# PostgreSQL dynamic date_trunc function rounding up exactly to given timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the built-in PostgreSQL-function date_trunc() to aggregate time windows like this:

```
SELECT max(time) as time, 
COUNT(*) as ticks 
FROM sensorticks 
WHERE time between (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 00:15:00') AND (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 14:15:00') 
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', time)
ORDER BY time desc;
```

The result is this:

```
time                        ticks
2019-01-04 14:14:59         892
2019-01-04 13:59:59         3575
2019-01-04 12:59:59         3552
2019-01-04 11:59:59         3560
2019-01-04 10:59:59         2671
```

But I don't want to cut off the first window. I need dynamic time windows from 14:15 onwards (14:15, 13:15, and so on). It should look like this:

```
time                        ticks
2019-01-04 14:14:59         3575
2019-01-04 13:14:59         3575
2019-01-04 12:14:59         3552
2019-01-04 11:14:59         3560
2019-01-04 10:14:59         3575
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the time window for your query depends on the upper range appearing in the `WHERE` clause.  Since it is 15 minutes past the hour, you may try aggregating with the time shifted forward by 45 minutes:

```
SELECT
    MAX(time) AS time, 
    COUNT(*) AS ticks 
FROM sensorticks 
WHERE time BETWEEN (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 00:15:00') AND (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 14:15:00') 
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', time + interval '45 minutes')
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

But the above query still has a problem, because the times displayed still might not be correct.  Also, some time slots may be missing, yet you still might want to report them.  To fix that, we can try using a calendar table:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 14:00:00' AS ts, TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 14:14:59' AS display UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 13:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 13:14:59' UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 12:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 12:14:59' UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 11:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 11:14:59' UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 10:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 10:14:59'
)
```

Then, we can join to this calendar table using the original query:

```
SELECT
    c.display AS time, 
    COUNT(*) AS ticks 
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN sensorticks s
    ON c.ts = date_trunc('hour', s.time + interval '45 minutes')
WHERE s.time BETWEEN (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 00:15:00') AND (TIMESTAMP'2019-01-04 14:15:00') 
GROUP BY c.display
ORDER BY c.display DESC;
```